# Anroid-layout How can make custom button like this?

Tags: android-layout

those three things are clickable buttons, I don't know how to make it....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eJ45.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Card(
          child: new InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  "Bignners Level Lessons",
                ),
                subtitle: Text("write your text"),
              ),
              height: 100.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Card(
          child: new InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  "Bignners Level Lessons",
                ),
                subtitle: Text("write your text"),
              ),
              height: 100.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Card(
          child: new InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  "Bignners Level Lessons",
                ),
                subtitle: Text("write your text"),
              ),
              height: 100.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65627207/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.